# How to change the pixel dimensions of the cube while keeping the cube intact?

Tags: css, 3d, transform, css-transforms, gsap

I am trying to change the cube dimensions to be 300x250px, however whenever I am doing that the cube faces start overlapping. How would I be able to change the translate values in order to accomplish that?

I tried changing the translate values in the CSS to percentages, but couldn't make it work either.

Here is my
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/dada78/pen/dEaBjx)

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
min-height: 100vh;
}
.container .cube-container {
perspective: 800px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
}
.container .cube-container .cube {
transition: transform 2s ease-in;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
margin: 50px 0;
}

.box {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
color: white;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.08em;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 500;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}

.box.front {
background: #40b9dc;
transform: translateZ(75px);
}

.box.back {
background: #3dbadf;
transform: translateZ(-75px) rotateY(180deg);
}

.box.top {
 background: #5acaec;
 transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-75px);
 transform-origin: top center;
}

.box.bottom {
background: #82daf4;
transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(75px);
transform-origin: bottom center;
}

.box.left {
background: #a3e5f9;
transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-75px);
transform-origin: center left;
}

.box.right {
background: #67d6f7;
transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(75px);
transform-origin: top right;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did my answer help you at all?

Answer (score 1):

I have made some edits to your code pen hoping it helps:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mdxebo
I think that main take away from what i've done is that both the top and bottom panels need different height values if your cube is going to be uneven.

```
.box.top {
  height: 84%;

  background: #5acaec;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-75px);
  transform-origin: top center;
}

.box.bottom {
  height: 84%;

  background: #82daf4;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(75px) translateZ(-48px);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```